# Simple AJAX query with CodeIgniter and jQuery

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, jquery, preventdefault

I'm simply trying to pull a div from a page called "Load-about.php" to my main page with AJAX.
I've been following tutsnet courses "30 Days to learn jQuery" but I'm stuck when it is about to load a content from another page since I'm using CI and I'm trying to adapt those courses.

So I have my main page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Load</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css'); ?>" >

    <style>
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <a href="<?php echo site_url('Ajax/lessonTwentyThree/Load-about'); ?>">Try to make AJAX working !</a>
    </br>
    <a href="<?php echo site_url('Ajax/lessonTwentyThree/Load-Contact'); ?>">Contact</a>

    <div class="wrap"></div>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
(function() {
    var wrap = $('div.wrap');

    $('a').on('click', function(e) {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        wrap.load(href +'.container' ) ;
         e.preventDefault();
    });

})();

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm simply calling a very simple CI Controller that only call the asked view
And Everything was working fine when working without the links.

But now, I am redirected to the page instead of using the AJAX call. Why ? Why does
e.preventDefault();
or
return false;
isn't preventing the links to their default action ?

Thanks

EDIT: Thanks to Jai, I found my error, a simple coma.
But, now, I'm getting "GET http://www.localhost.com/CodeIgniterJQUERY/index.php/Ajax/lessonTwentyThree/Load-Contact.container 500 (Internal Server Error) "

the problem comes from the .container as I wanted to specify the class and Ci understand it as it is a parameter.

Here is the Controller :

class Ajax extends CI_Controller {

```
    /**
     * Nous allons ici nous occuper de toutes les fcts AJAX
     */

    public function lessonTwentyThree($page)
    { // En fait, on a pas besoin de ca, on va directement loader la vue directement.
        $this->load->view($page);
    }

}
```

I just want to grab a div from Load-Contact to the main page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In addition to what Jai said**. you have a codeigniter **logical** error.

when you say:

```
$this->load->view($page);
```

it means that codeigniter will redirect internally to the view. In your case what you need is to get back the view content and not to load it.

So, codeigniter support a third parameter with function `view()` that asks it to get the view content as `String`. you can do that and send the view to be loaded like this:

```
$string = $this->load->view($page, '', true);
echo $string;
```

Hope this will solve your problem

Comment: Thank you Mamdouh, I wasn't aware of that logic.

Answer (score 2):

You have to move it up:

```
(function($) {
    var wrap = $('div.wrap');

    $('a').on('click', function(e) {
       e.preventDefault(); 
       var href = $(this).attr('href');
       wrap.load(href +'.container' ) ;
    });
})(jQuery);
```

and **you have to put a `','` after click handler**.

Comment: Thanks, but same thing, I'm still redirected to http://www.localhost.com/CodeIgniterJQUERY/index.php/Ajax/lessonTwentyThree/Load-about
What do you mean by "you have to put a ',' after click handler." I don't see where I should put that coma

Comment: you have mentioned in your answer `$('a').on('click' function(e) {` here after `click` a `','` is missing.

Comment: Thanks, ufortunately, I'm getting a different error, please check the edit

Answer (score 0):

also try to change

```
(function() {


})();
```

to

```
$(function() {


});
```

Comment: Thanks, but same thing, I'm still redirected to http://www.localhost.com/CodeIgniterJQUERY/index.php/Ajax/lessonTwentyThree/Load-about